# Laravel - errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed in migration

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-8 application, I have this migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('first_name',50);
        $table->string('last_name',50);
        $table->string('other_name',50)->nullable();
        $table->string('gender',20);
        $table->string('user_photo',350)->nullable();
        $table->integer('nationality_id');
        $table->string('marital_status',50);
        $table->date('dob')->nullable();
        $table->string('address', 300)->nullable();
        $table->integer('country_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('state_id')->nullable();
        $table->integer('city_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('cv_file',350)->nullable();
        $table->text('summary')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('nationality_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
        $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
        $table->foreign('state_id')->references('id')->on('state_origins');
        $table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('cities');
    });
}
```

When I did php artisan migrate, I got this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `hrm`.`profiles` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `profiles` add constraint `profiles_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

This is the users table:

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name', 100)->nullable();
        $table->string('email', 80)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('avatar', 200)->nullable();
        $table->boolean('active')->default(false);
        $table->string('activation_token', 250)->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes()->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_login_at')->nullable();
    });
}
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: All your foreign key need to be unsigned,  change `bigInteger` to `unsignedBigInteger`, `primary` and `foreign references` must be of same type. `bigIncrements()` needs `unsignedBigInteger()` and `increments()` needs `unsignedInteger()`

Comment: Well I think your mysql server has problem. I ran your code in my wampserver and table created without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your foreign key need to be unsigned,  change `bigInteger` to `unsignedBigInteger`

**primary** and **foreign** references must be of same type. `bigIncrements()` needs `unsignedBigInteger()` and `increments()` needs `unsignedInteger()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run all migrations that you use as foreign key table inside a table. Like, you define `user_id` as foreign in `profile` table, then must you have to run the `user` migration before the `profile` migration file. And it will be the same process for all other's. And make sure the foreign key is defined with `unsignedBigInteger()`

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')
```